# Java passing same set of value object to different jar

Tags: java

I want to pass Set of values to a another jar file which uses same set of value.

For example :
Application X has object C
Application Y has object C

I want to pass C to Application Y from Application X.

**Appication X**

```
CDAO{// consider this as class in application X
    public void insert(C obj){
        //do stuff
        anotherApp.insert(obj); // consider this as a method in application Y
    }
}
```

Comment: Any efforts to show? Code snippet?

Comment: hope in order now. @m.rogalski

Comment: anything to do with generics or serialization?

Comment: What do you mean by "application"? Are talking about two threads? Two processes?

Comment: Your code sample doesn't make sense. If `CDAO` is a class, then it should have the `class` keyword in front of it. I still don't know what you mean by "application", but by every definition I can think of, if a method is in a class belonging to "application X", then the method belongs to "application X". This is why you have three "unclear what you are asking" votes.

Comment: Ok. I get that this is not clear. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the full qualified path of the respective C, like com.snfrox.X.C and com.snfrox.Y.C

Comment: This answer is not complete.

Comment: True. But not sure this is best way to do it.

Comment: "not complete" as in "it depends"? I guess Application X has a C and Y has a (but not the same) C. What am I missing?